# automatically logging out of user after uncertain time

Tags: authentication

when user logs in to my site the cookies expire after a month still it gets logs out after 10 - 20 mins , its uncertain I will provide you my codes that I use  to login, for cookie and webconfig authentication

here are the codes

code at login

```
       Dim cookie As HttpCookie = FormsAuthentication.GetAuthCookie(usernameforcookie, _
                           keepme.Checked)
                ' Expires in 30 days, 12 hours and 30 minutes from today.
                cookie.Expires = DateTime.Now.Add(New TimeSpan(30, 0, 0, 0))
                Response.Cookies.Add(cookie)
                Response.Redirect("Home.aspx")
```

here the cookies are saved for one month

and in main web config file I set

```
       <authentication mode="Forms">
       <forms  loginUrl="Login.aspx" />
        </authentication>
         <authorization>
        <deny users="?"/>
         </authorization>
        <customErrors mode="Off"/>
```

Plus I have many webconfig for example in forum folder, because here the forum can be viewed by any person so I authenticated the user by giving authentication , below are the code in web config for forum

```
      <authorization>
  <allow users ="*"/>
  <deny users="?"/>
</authorization>
```

Now the Problem is ..
the user gets logged out automatically after Uncertain time means sometime after 10 mins sometimes after 30 mins  , but works fine at development server

Answer (score 0):

I am facing similar issue as well. After research of days, I came across various reasons that can led to the issue you are facing. Following are the points that you want to check before you dig in further.

1.Mentioning Timeout and cookies in Authentication Block.
`<authentication mode="Forms">
       <forms  loginUrl="Login.aspx" timeout="43260" cookieless="UseCookies" />
        </authentication>`

This will make sure that the Form is active for 30 days.

2. Session Values.
Make sure that your session timeout and other values are similar to form.
`<sessionState cookieless="UseCookies" timeout="21630" />(This will also update your session value on IIS)`

3. Check Application Pool recycling intervals. When an app pool is recycled, it kills all sessions and form authentication.

4. Make sure that session is alive and not being killed in the code.